# VM3317:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token z in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

The title is the error I get. ATM I am upgrading the api to a higher version. Now i got this error. I have tried to fix it but no chance for me. Can someone help?

The code that gives the error is

```
appendCalls(callList = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
```

The whole function:

```
function getCallList() {
        var date = formatDate(currentDisplayDate);
        callCounter = 0;
        unansweredCalls = 0;
        
        $('#callCounter').html('');
        $('#spinner').addClass('display');
            
        xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
            console.log("sd1"); 
            if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
                console.log("sd2"); 
                appendCalls(callList = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                console.log("sd3"); 
            }
        }
    
        xhr.open("GET","/api.php?f=calllist&date="+date,true);
        xhr.send();
        
    }
```

"appendCalls" is another function. If you need it I can post it.

Comment: Please include JSON code returned by your API call in the question.

Comment: Try log the contents of `xhr.responseText` and see what is actually being returned, as it looks like the response starts with a 'z' and is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I checked the output (idk why I don't thought about that) and saw I had an console output that was starting with an 'z'. It works now so Thanks!